# Valid name attribute strings in R

Tags: r, names

What are the set of rules for what R considers a valid name attribute string for use in lists for my case, but the rules should apply to anything R can grant a name to I'd imagine. Reading the section in the R language definition [2 Objects; 2.2 Attributes, 2.2.1 Names](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Names) I don't see any real restrictions mentioned.

I'm modifying some lists that will be built up into a Pandas dataframe in Python and I'd like to define in R the formatted column headers that will ultimately wind up in a csv and html report. I've tried the following which is about as complicated a name that will show up in our report so I know it will work for my use cases, but it would be valuable to know in advance what I could and could not define as a name.

```
>  v = list(c=0, 'd cef'=0, 'Conc[K/L]'=0.123, '%LVR'=0.98)
> str(v)
List of 4
 $ c        : num 0
 $ d cef    : num 0
 $ Conc[K/L]: num 0.123
 $ %LVR     : num 0.98
> v$'%LVR' = 0.5
> v$'Conc[K/L]' = 0.5
> str(v)
List of 4
 $ c        : num 0
 $ d cef    : num 0
 $ Conc[K/L]: num 0.5
 $ %LVR     : num 0.5
```

Seems safe enough just by experiment, and going further into the language definition the only real restriction I could find was the following

> [10.3.3 Reserved
>   words](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Reserved-words)
>   The following identifiers have a special meaning and cannot be used
>   for object names
>
> ```
> if else repeat while function for in next break TRUE FALSE NULL Inf
> NaN NA NA_integer_ NA_real_ NA_complex_ NA_character_ ... ..1 ..2 etc.
> ```

Seems like beyond those keyword restrictions anything goes, maybe length restrictions, not really sure. names and identifiers are different concepts so the rules for valid identifiers don't hold here.

Just for kicks here's the sort of errors you get in using the above keywords.

```
> v$TRUE = 99
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "v$TRUE"
> v$else = 99
Error: unexpected 'else' in "v$else"
```

Comment: The restrictions on variable names and `$` syntax are not the same as the restrictions on column names. For example, `v <- list("else" = 1:5); v[["else"]]` works, as does `v$"else"`. Same with `NA` and other column names. For data.frames, you have to be a bit more circumspect since it runs it through `make.names` when constructing, but `v <- data.frame(a = 1:5); colnames(v) <- "else"; v[["else"]]` works

Comment: The `make.names` function is worth taking a look at. When you define a data frame in R, `make.names` ensures the names are syntactically valid. For example, `make.names(c("else", "NA", "NA_real_"))` returns `[1] "else."     "NA."       "NA_real_."`

Comment: Interesting one! But I think its validation rules are different.
`> make.names('Conc[K/L]')
[1] "Conc.K.L."`, looks like it does character substitution

Comment: What would you expect it to return? `Conc[K/L` is not a valid object name, and `v$Conc[K/L` will not work.

Comment: Again, you always *can* title your column `my column name w/ spaces; if else NA`. It is just less convenient since you'll need to retrieve it with something like `v$'my column name w/ spaces; if else NA'`, and you can't use it in a formula or a ggplot2 call

Comment: So I guess the distinction is really about column names, which are different it sounds from object names. Is an object name synonymous with a variable identifier?

Comment: Yes (or at least, I'm referring to the same thing). There are almost no restrictions on column names, assuming you don't try to use them like `v$else` without quotes or in a formula. The empty string is the only problem I can think of.

Comment: That usability aspect with downstream function usage may be a dealbreaker for the tradeoff with readability in a report. Might just delegate that step with a variable name lookup formatting translator. Good to know! Interesting too the distinction with lists being so loose but data.frame's being more strict on these tag namings. Data frames definitely are making a call to make.names(). Thanks David.